# Higher weight for Title - text Indexing

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to create a index for free text search with additional weight for title.. but when the index is created.. I am still seeing the weight as $** : 1

```
db.record.ensureIndex( {  "$**": "text" },
                   { language_override: "english" }, { "weights": { title: 2}} )
```

text weight after the index has been created is $**
    {
    "$**" : 1
    }

any ideas on how to give higher preference to title when compare to other text fields

Comment: @veeram please advise if you have any insights on this issue

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39592234/mongodb-text-index-wildcard-weight

Comment: Thank you @N3i1.. that was my guess too.. now it is confirmed